# programmatically add an existing entity reference autocomplete field in custom form

Tags: 7, forms, entities

I need to create a custom form and add an entity reference field to it. The field uses autocomplete with a view for entity selection. The field already exists on a node but i also need it in a custom module. Is there a way to add this field in a custom module with `MYMODULE_MYFORM_form()`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the references module's node_reference field, then, in your custom form, you'll want to create a field that uses the node_reference's autocomplete, like so:

```
$form['referenced_field'] = array(
  '#title' => 'Referenced field title',
  '#description' => t('Referenced field description.'),
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#autocomplete_path' => 'node_reference/autocomplete',
  '#required' => TRUE,  // Optional depending on your circumstance.
);
```

See node_reference.module line 892 for more details on parameters, etc.

Comment: i am using the `entity reference` module and since there wasn't a replay for a couple days, i've implemented this in a different way. didn't managed to get it to work within the form. thanks anyway for your help